# Session Guarantee on DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to understand the exact guarantees provided by DocumentDB when using session consistency.

Is it possible for the following to happen (lets assume a,b,c,d are all values of the same document)

Session 1 W(a) W(b)

Session 2..................W(c)W(d)

Session 3.................................                R(b)R(c)

Session 4................................                 R(c)R(b)

In other words, are writes across sessions ordered (in which case, either b happens before c or c happens before b, so one of C3 or C4 will violate monotonic reads)?

In what order will the updates a,b,c,d (assuming they are all made with session consistency) be applied?

Comment: What do the C1, C2, etc. represent? Are they different "clients"? Session consistency just means that for a given session, the database will appear consistent, ready your own writes/monotonic. However, from another session, they can appear completely out of order. In your example, you do reads after writes, so this may not apply, but if you do writes after reads, you can use the Etag optimistic concurrency functionality to be certain that the document hasn't be updated between the two. Also, if you combine all of your reads and writes into a stored procedure, they are fully ACID transactional.

Comment: Yes, the represent different clients. Are there any guarantees on the final ordering of the updates? (assuming there's no more updates after what I showed, will the final state be either d or b?). 

I'm not sure i get your point about etags. etags make sense with strong consistency, but writes happen asynchronously. Say, I read r(a) then want to write w(c), there's no guarantee that write(b) is in transit and will be applied in between my read(a) and write(b), right? (when i first applied w(b), the document still had value a so the etag check wouldn't fail).

Comment: "Say, I read r(a) then want to write w(c), there's no guarantee that write(b) is in transit and will be applied in between my read(a) and write(b), right?" You can guarantee that write(c) will fail if write(b) occurs between read(a) and write(c) with Etags.

Comment: If using strong consistency, yes. If using only session consistency, how would you achieve it? If I write c from my session bound replica (r1) , and write b was written to a different replica (r2), but not yet propagated, how will my write c fail? The etag check on applying write c will succeed on r1, as b hasn't yet reached r1.

Comment: In that scenario, then write(b) would fail because its etag would be invalidated by write(c). I could be wrong but I believe that even with session consistency, the propagation of a particular write is not a worry. MongoDB accomplishes this by directing all writes to a single replica. Reads can come from many places. Not sure if DocumentDB does this. That said, I would defer to the DocumentDB Product Managers who monitor for a more confident answer.

Comment: That's precisely my problem, the only documentation i've been able to find is that reads go from the "session bound replica" but I haven't been able to find information about writes (whether there's a single primary, or whether they also go to the session bound replica).

Answer (score 2):

Session Consistency provides following guarantees to user.

1) Read Your Own Write- Any write performed inside the session is immediately visible inside the session.

2) Monotonic Read - Any read seen inside a session will not regress within a session.

Assuming A,B,C,D are increasing version of same document.

C, B is not a monotonic increasing history and will be violation of session guarantee.

Note: The assumption here is read requests by Session(4) are issued in serial order. i.e. Second read is issued after completion of first read.

Comment: B and C are written by different clients though. Does it still hold? Does this mean I can assume that all writes will go through a single primary?

When you mean "regress", do you mean regress with respect to my own writes, or to the total order of writes in the document (here A,B,C,D even though A,B,C,D weren't written by Session 4)

Comment: Yes, irrespective of which session performed writes, you will see monotonic read guarantees within *every* session.

Comment: Does this apply also across documents within the same collection?
If client 1 write version 1 of document A, then writes version 1 of document b: if client 2 then reads version 1 of document B, will it also be guaranteed to see version 1 of document A? (are session guarantees guaranteed at the level of documents, collections or databases?)

Comment: Yes as long as they are within the same partition(identified by partition key) this guarantee is valid.