# Document DB - ETag Optimistic Concurrency with Session Consistency

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

If I have a DocumentDB database with Session consistency, what guarantees are there for concurrent writes of the same document using etags?  For example, with A and B operating in different sessions:

- Read:A - etag:1
- Read:B - etag:1
- Write:A - etag:1 (match, etag = 2)
- Write:B - etag:1 ?

The assumption is that Write:B fails since etag is 2, but I haven't found any *explicit* documentation on what guarantee there is for where DocumentDB reads the etag value from on the server, as in, **could it read from a secondary replica where the etag is still 1, and let Write:B still go through**?

This question [Session Guarantee on DocumentDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415310/session-guarantee-on-documentdb/36415985#36415985) discusses the issue in the comments, but does not seem to come to a conclusion.

---

#### Web Documentation

From the FAQ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-faq
[image]

From the example source (implies, but does not state, that this holds true at all consistency levels?)  https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs:
[image]

Comment: With most master-replica systems, writes typically go through a single or limited set of replicas. This makes it easier to enforce eTag consistency. Even if DocumentDB is not implemented with a master-replica approach, the guarantee that you can't update a document with the wrong eTag is possible to be enforced. I believe this to be true in my experience regardless of the consistency model that's in force although eTag checking might not be necessary in some of those consistency models.

Comment: Thanks @LarryMaccherone.  All signs seem to point to yes.  I just wish there was official word somewhere.  Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DocumentDB team member here. Confirming Larry's reply that conditional writes with ETags will be enforced for all consistency levels. The write request must include the ETag (If-Match header in REST, RequestOptions.AccessCondition in .NET).

**EDIT on 7/29/2019** with accounts configured for multi-region writes, there are no guarantees for ETag with multi-region writers, and you have to resolve concurrent writes via conflict resolution procedures. ETag validation still applies for single-region write accounts, as before.

Comment: "enforced except regardless" is a little confusing, but it seems you're saying that if the etag is provided, then write concurrency is enforced independent of configured consistency level.  Thanks for getting back to me!