# DocumentDB optimistic concurrency writes and stale re-reads

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662399/document-db-etag-optimistic-concurrency-with-session-consistency/40663271#40663271) I understand that when updating a document in DocumentDB with If-Match ETag, this update will fail if there's a newer version of the document written, regardless of the chosen consistency level.

I assume that also implies that if I'm using lower consistency level and get a stale read, then try to perform update with an ETag from this read, it should fail even though the conflicting modification technically occurred before I even started the read?

The common solution would be to re-read the document again, make modifications again and try writing again. However I don't understand how does this work with the consistency levels. Won't I get a stale read again (even assuming there were no further concurrent writes) or does DocumentDB somehow ensure I get the latest copy after failed write? Can that lead to a significant number of re-reads (without max attempts), until one of them reads the most recent document?

That also brings a related secondary question: What is the typical staleness (in other words, how long does it take for changes to propagate through to all replicas) I can expect with the lower consistency levels (primarily Session consistency)? I understand it'll probably wary a lot based on load, configuration and so on, but is it in order of milliseconds, seconds, minutes or even hours?

Thanks for your answers in advance, I really enjoy learning and working with DocumentDB, but this is something I didn't manage to find a clear answer for in the documentation and examples.