# Confusion on how updates work with weak consistency models

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

When using a non-strong consistency model and updating a document, it seems there is always a chance cosmos could override my changes. I'm obviously missing something here with my thinking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use optimistic concurrency controls to enforce monotonic writes across all consistency modes. This was more or less answered here: [Document DB - ETag Optimistic Concurrency with Session Consistency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662399/document-db-etag-optimistic-concurrency-with-session-consistency/40663271)

Essentially, if you set AccessCondidion on the request options and set it to the ETag of the item you're updating, then you'll be guaranteed correctness across all consistency models.

See here this code sample for an example in C#: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-dotnet/blob/master/samples/code-samples/DocumentManagement/Program.cs#L433 (If you want a different language just ask )

Comment: So if I try to update a doc under event consistency with an eTag and I get a conflict back, how do I make a request to get the most current version? i can make another call but again it's eventually consistent so who knows how many calls it will take me to read the most current record. as a side note, if i just put this behavior in a stored procedure and perform a read, will this ensure i get back the most recent?

Comment: " if i just put this behavior in a stored procedure and perform a read, will this ensure i get back the most recent?". from what i read i can only read from the current partition key so that wont work either :/

Comment: You're correct that if you keep updating the same record, you're more likely to run into conflicts. Even a stored procedure might have the same problem, depending on how it's written But this is the problem with updating a single record many times. Either you have everyone line up single file to update that record, to avoid any conflicts in the first place, or you accept async orders and deal with conflicts as they arrive - the more orders, the more conflicts.

Comment: My preference for a design would be a single actor that owns updating the record, but folks can leave orders to update it on another collection/partition/etc. This avoids publishers pressuring a record too much, and concentrates responsibility for the hot object, which can do updates in batches (so it doesn't need to apply every change individually, saving RUs/etc.) and it owns the record, so it avoids ETag conflicts.

Comment: that sounds awesome. got a link by chance on how i could use actors?

Comment: Akka.NET is popular http://getakka.net/

Service Fabric is a service Azure has which offers similar Actor functionality.

Durable Functions doesn't have an actor pattern, per say, but can offer some similar benefits. It won't scale to the same degree that proper actor frameworks do, though it does scale pretty well.

Additionally, Azure Functions Change Feed trigger batches by partition, so it will give similar benefits, though it is not an actor at all.

Comment: great info! good point on the change feed behaving somewhat of an actor. one more thing. do you know of any examples that demo the various consistencies? i read the local emulator does not provide this.

Comment: Don't know any demos necessarily that show it, but the UI in the portal with the music notes is my favorite visual representation of the differences.